# Index of lua api c starts at 10

Tags: c, lua

Well, I would like a better explanation of how the stack index works in lua in my case

I have a table where inside it I have some fields and a subtable.

**Table:**

```
local mytable = {
    enable = true,
    timer = 60,
    subtable = {
        key1 = "value1",
        key2 = "value2",
    },
    subtable2 = {
        key1 = "value3",
        key2 = "value4"
    },
}
```

**C code:**

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int read_nested_table(lua_State *L) {
    bool enable = lua_toboolean(L, 1);
    int timer = lua_tointeger(L, 2);
    
    luaL_checktype(L, 3, LUA_TTABLE);
    lua_settop(L, 3);
    lua_pushnil(L);
    while (lua_next(L, 3) != 0) {
        const char *key = lua_tostring(L, 4);
        const char *value = lua_tostring(L, 5);
        printf("%s: %s\n", key, value);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    lua_settop(L, 4);
    luaL_checktype(L, 4, LUA_TTABLE); // returning nil
    lua_pushnil(L);
    while (lua_next(L, 4) != 0) {
        const char *key = lua_tostring(L, 5);
        const char *value = lua_tostring(L, 6);
        printf("%s: %s\n", key, value);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_register(L, "read_nested_table", read_nested_table);

    if (luaL_dofile(L, "myscript.lua") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    }

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

The code works as expected, the issue here is the index

Note that in `const char *key` and `const char *value` I used the **negative index**

Now when I try to use the positive index like for example:

```
while (lua_next(L, 3) != 0) {
     const char *key = lua_tostring(L, 4);
     const char *value = lua_tostring(L, 5);
     printf("%s: %s\n", key, value);
     lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

I don't have correct return of the values.

Now if I use index **11** and **12** both return the value
again

So the code to work using positive index is

```
while (lua_next(L, 3) != 0) {
        const char *key = lua_tostring(L, 11);
        const char *value = lua_tostring(L, 12);
        printf("%s: %s\n", key, value);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

My index is starting at 10 how can I fix this so I can use **index** `4` and `5` to receive **key** and **value**?

Comment: The sample you provided does not seem to produce problem you are describing. Negative and positive indices provide me equal results. As in your case negative indices work alright, I would check out if you correctly popping values that you put on the stack. Also you can just dump stack content to inspect (http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2017-12/msg00068.html). Since _myscript.lua_ is missing an invocation of `read_nested_table` my guess is that your sample is trimmed and incomplete.

Comment: It seems the `myscript.lua` file should be appended with `read_nested_table(mytable.enable, mytable.timer, mytable.subtable)`

Comment: Well, that seems reasonable, but that works correctly in both cases. Since the provided sample works, it's either that the implementation that produces error is different (and maybe forgets to pop something at some point), function is called with more than three arguments, or something completely different. Stack dump, checking `lua_gettop` or any debugging should be able to clear it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass 10 arguments to the Lua function `read_nested_table` then available indices in Lua API stack start with 11.
You should invoke `lua_settop(L, 3);` right before `lua_pushnil(L);` to make sure exactly 3 stack slots are occupied by input parameters and indices 4,5,... of Lua API stack are available for your C code.

Comment: A question regarding `lua_settop`, if I add new tables after the **subtable** table for example, and I define `lua_settop(L, 4);` after reading the loop `lua_next` index **3** I have the return of nil for index **4**, can you tell me why this happens?

I edited the post code to illustrate this.

Comment: After invoking `lua_settop(L, 3);` all arguments at stack slots 4,5,6,... are erased.  You should invoke `lua_settop(L, how_many_arguments_you_expect);` instead.